# CSS Formatting with Form and Tabs Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have come across a unique situation with HTML and CSS. I have made a form with simple input text boxes and drop downs to be filled out and submitted. However, I now want to add tabs to the top of the form and I realized that I have wrapped my html code with a div form container (#form_container) and now when I try to apply any css on that alone, it keeps throwing off the css of the form, or the css on the tabs just doesn't work. The css that I used just to test out the changes on the tabs are .tabs a {....} located below.

My HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>This is my title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="view.css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>


</head>
<body id="main_body" >

    <img id="top" src="top.png" alt="">
    <div id="form_container">

        <h1><a>Example</a></h1>
        <form id="form" class="myForm"  method="post" action="get.php">
        <div class="form_description">
            <h2>Example</h2>
            <p>Please Fill Out the Fields Below.</p>

        </div>                      
        <ul >

        <li class="tabs">
        <nav id="tab">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">Topics</a>
        </nav>  
        </li>

        <li id="profile">
        <label class="description" for="">Please select your profile by clicking the button or continuing below:
        </label>
        <div>
            <input id="profilebutton" type="button" name="prof" class="button_text" value="Select Profile">
        </div>
        </li>


        <!--First Name Input--> 

        <li id="FirstName" >
        <label class="description" for="firstname">First Name </label>
        <div>
            <input id="firstname" name="firstname" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>       

        <!--Last Name Input-->

        <li id="LastName" >
        <label class="description" for="lastname">Last Name </label>
        <div>
            <input id="lastname" name="lastname" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>


        <li id="age" >
        <label class="description" for="age">Age </label>
        <div>
            <input id="age" name="age" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>       



        <li class="buttons">
            <input type="hidden" name="form_id"  />

            <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
            <input type="reset" class="button_text" id="resetForm" name="reset" value="Reset" />
        </li>
            </ul>

        </form> 

    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

My CSS is:

```
body
{
    background:#336699;
    font-family:"Lucida Grande", Tahoma, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size:small;
    margin:8px 0 16px;
    text-align:center;
}

.rupreg{
    display:none;
}


.tabs a {
    display: block;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: #dddddd;
}

#form_container
{
    background:#fff;

    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:left;
    width:640px;
}

#top
{
    display:block;
    height:10px;
    margin:10px auto 0;
    width:650px;
}

#footer
{
    width:640px;
    clear:both;
    color:#999999;
    text-align:center;
    width:640px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    font-size: 85%;
}

#footer a{
    color:#999999;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #999999;
}

#bottom
{
    display:block;
    height:10px;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:650px;
}

form.myForm
{
    margin:20px 20px 0;
    padding:0 0 20px;
}

/**** Logo Section  *****/
h1
{
    background-color:#6699CC;
    margin:0;
    min-height:0;
    padding:0;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-indent:-8000px;

}

h1 a
{

    display:block;
    height:100%;
    min-height:40px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Is there anything anyone can reccommend? Should I make a separate css class and override it? Thanks.

Comment: create fiddle for your question https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Show us your html code

Comment: @leo.fcx I had to re-do it since the first time I submitted it, I messed it up. The html code is now up. Thanks

Comment: I don't see the 'tabs' in your html code

Comment: @leo.fcx sorry about that! I had two different files. It's up now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to create nav tabs above your form:

- Remove the tabs from the form container altogether and place them above it and below the img tag.
- This keeps your css separated as well.

If you want your nav tabs inside the form (not sure I see why):

- Target you nav tabs as directly as you can and place the css below that of the container css.
- CSS: over-writes itself based on specificity, which means if you are more specific when you target the nav tabs than you are when you target the container, the nav-tab css will take precedence.

For example:
`#form_container #form .tabs #tab a  {text-decoration: none}`
Supersedes: `#form_container`